# ckeditor inserts multiple span tags while applying styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In ckeditor, instead of styles, I want to have classes for all styles. So I have used the following configuration.

config.coreStyles_bold = { element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'Bold' }, };

config.coreStyles_italic = { element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'Italic' }, };

The Bold and Italic classes are defined in my contentsCss file.

But suppose I have following text in my editor

```
Sky is blue.
```

If I apply Bold and then Italic on this. Then generated output is :

```
<span class = 'Italic'> <span class='Bold'> Sky is blue </span> </span>
```

i.e. two different tags for Bold and Italic are being generated.

Whereas I would like to have the following output :

```
<span class='Italic Bold'> Sky is blue </span>
```

Is it possible ? Note : I am using CKeditor 4.4.1

Comment: Have you found any solution??
If yes then please share it helps others and save some time.